# In VBA, is it possible to select a cell relative to a dynamic range?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I set 'Rng' as a dynamic range, like ("A" & i) where 'i=2' and i increases by 1 whenever a certain condition is met. At the same time, I also set 'k = 2' and increase k whenever another condition is met. Is it possible to write a command that says 'If.... Then Copy "the cell on the top row of whatever column 'rng.offset(0,k)' happens to be at the moment?"

It would be easy to write this as another Offset command, but if the column and row of Rng is changing, is it possible to write a command that copies the top row of this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: the cell on the top row would be sheet.cells(1,"k")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cell on the top row would be sheet.cells(1,"k")–